# Switched from virtualenv uwsgi to global uwsgi and site-packages seems not to be found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, uwsgi

**I followed this guide:** https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Switching from a virtualenv uwsgi install to a global uwsgi produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/MyServer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/var/MyServer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 3, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/datetime.py", line 7, in <module>
    import time as _time
ImportError: No module named 'time'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

Am I correct in understanding where my problem lies, and how can I resolve this issue?

By the way, I am using Python 3.4

Comment: `time` is a built-in module, and as the documentation states, "this module is always available". Something fishy is going on. Do you happen to have a file `time.py` lying around somewhere else? In your app or in relevant directory that could be on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Thanks, I must have mixed it up for one I'm importing (datetime?) It doesn't seem that I have a copy of time.py on my entire machine. `find -iname "time.py"` returns nothing.

Comment: You won't find a module time.py in the normal Python distribution, since it is *built-in*: it's a direct interface to the C library. That's why it should exist. The reason it fails to indicate *might* indicate it's trying to import the time module from elsewhere (hence the `time.py` file question) what is a bad file, but that doesn't appear the case here.

Comment: Is your virtualenv installed in `/var/MyServer`? Because usually, one installs a virtualenv in a home directory, not in `/var/`. Further, if you do install and use a system-wide uwsgi, you shouldn't use a virtualenv anymore; deactive it.